# Convert ICO icon file to PNG image file using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to..

- .. convert an ICO file (e.g. http://www.google.com/favicon.ico ) to a PNG file after I downloaded it.
- .. preserve transparency.
- .. apply the solution in a node.js application.

I *don't* want to and already tried to ..

- .. use native tools such as imagemagick (that's what I *currently* use in my application, but it's really bad for maintaining platform independency).
- .. use tools that internally use native tools (e.g. [gm.js](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/)).
- .. rely on webservices such as http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.google.de that don't allow configuring the resulting size or require payments or logins.

Therefore I'd love a Javascript-only solution. I used [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) in another application, but it does not support ICO files.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you attempted anything in terms of a JavaScript solution?

Comment: I don't understand. You mean, whether if I tried to code it in plain-old JS myself? Yes, I am currently exploring that possibility. But it really sounds to me,  that I am not the first developer to have this requirement.

Comment: Have you tried using browser (electron?) to load image, draw it on canvas and then generate PNG from it? Not so optimal, but should work. Another way is writing ico decoder - format does not seem overly complicated, and if you're lucky, ico file will already contain PNG images: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)

Comment: _First idea_: Currently fiddling around with it. @paul kind of suggested something similar. _Second idea_: Yeah, that's what I started initially. Wanted to go back to it, if there is no hack'ish solution. 
Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, that's a tough one.  I haven't found a nice soltion yet. All the canvas-experiments had the problem, that I was able to create PNG files displayable by the default OS image viewers, but nothing worked with electron as app icon. I started the [ICO-parsing](https://gist.github.com/BastiTee/b6287ac3f8bbe6c02003f67bf5959e32) but didn't manage to get it working fully. Furthermore I saw that electron has an open issue on [supporting ICO-files](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2277). So far, so not good.

Comment: More references I've found: [A php-implementation](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2369-PHP-Extract-graphics-from-ico-files-into-PNG-images.html#view_files/files/9705) to parse ICO files, [ImageMagick source code](http://git.imagemagick.org/repos/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/icon.c) for reading ICOs, a [good header description](https://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-ico) for icos.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)  . Convert the Base64 to a data/png. Done.

```
const inputFile = __dirname + "/favicon.ico";
const outputFile = __dirname + "/favicon.png";

(function( inputFile, outputFile ) {

const fileApi = require("file-api");
const fs = require("fs");
const File = fileApi.File;
var fileReader = new fileApi.FileReader();
fileReader.readAsDataURL(new File(inputFile));
fileReader.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {
    var rawdata = ev.target.result;
    rawdata = rawdata.replace(/.*base64,/, "");
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, rawdata, "base64");
});

})(inputFile, outputFile);
```

Comment: Hmm, that does work, but only partly. The effect is the same as just renaming it to PNG. It'll work with image viewers that know how to handle it. But I still run into problems using it with Electron as app icon (in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Node environment but I wrote this ES6 module [PNG2ICOjs](https://github.com/datvm/PNG2ICOjs) using purely Javascript `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob` and can 100% run on client-side browsers (I assume Node file should act like a Blob).

```
import { PngIcoConverter } from "../src/png2icojs.js";

// ...

const inputs = [...files].map(file => ({
    png: file
}));

// Result is a Blob
const resultBlob1 = await converter.convertToBlobAsync(inputs); // Default mime type is image/x-icon
const resultBlob2 = await converter.convertToBlobAsync(inputs, "image/your-own-mime");

// Result is an Uint8Array
const resultArr = await converter.convertAsync(inputs);
```